# Example of topological space where pseudo-component differ with intersection of clopen sets.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

It is well known fact that connected component $C_x$ of a point $x$ from some topological space $\tau$ is contained in every clopen set containing $x$ (so it's intersection $M$ also contains $C_x$). We know that when $\tau$ is compact then mentioned intersection $M$ equals to $C_x$, too. Hence my question: what is counterexample for non-compact $\tau$ where $C_x$ differs with $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$,

$$X = \{ (0,0), (0,1)\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{\frac1n\right\} \times [0,1].$$

Every clopen set containing $(0,0)$ also contains $(0,1)$.